# Windows Mobile - Localization

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, localization, compact-framework

I need to create Localized Windows Mobile Application. I seen some videos from MSDN. But, all requires either Satelite assemblies or separate forms resources for each language. This will increase the size of executable. I am storing localized text in SQLite database which I need to show on Buttons, MessageBoxes etc.

How Can I show localized text on UI Controls (Fetching from DB is not a problem)? When I try to show Hindi (India) language text on Button, it shows junk characters.

Is there anything like Culture, Character set that needs to be set to show Hindi (India) text on UI without creating any resource file (directly from database)? I need to support many languages and my main server will provide me localized resources to store in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the localized string from the database but it's not displaying properly, then it's not a problem of the text, it's a problem of the font.  The Font you're using likely doesn't have the Hindi glyphs you're requesting.  Get a Font (legally) that you can distribute with the app that does support them.

Comment: Can you elaborate "legally". Is it legal to transfer font from PC to Mobile?

Comment: No, it is not legal to take your PC Fonts and distribute them.  You must purchase a font that you have the right to redistribute.  fonts.com and myfonts.com have loads of them.